# Select a cell in VBA that depends on a formula on excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am try to use a cell in VBA that depends on a formula on Excel sheet.

Lets say I made a formula in a cell "A1" that return value "B2" by using a formula.

I want to use this returned value in a macro so for example I can make Range("B2").Value = 0

I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value of cell A1 in a string variable and then make use of that string variable in the code.

```
Dim strVar As String
strVar = Range("A1").Value
Range(strVar).Value = 100
```